# What is the size of 'ptr'?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, string-literals

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char *s[] = {"ice","green","cone","please"};
   char **ptr[] = {s+3,s+2,s+1,s};
   char ***p = ptr;
   
   printf("%s\n",**++p);
   
   printf("%s\n",*--*++p + 3);
   
   printf("%s\n",*p[-2]+3);
   
   printf("%s\n",p[-1][-1] + 1);
   
    
   return 0;
}
```

My doubt is how many bytes of memory will be allocated to ptr?

Some considerations:

1. char **ptr[] ; // ptr is an array of elements which are a pointer to a pointer to elements of character datatype.
2. So basically ptr is an array of pointers ( which are itself pointers)
3. And since every pointer is of unsigned int data type hence the size of ptr array should be = (no. of elements x size of a pointer)
4. Here no. of elements is 4 and let’s assume size of a pointer ( in 64 bit system ) is 8 bytes
5. Hence size of ptr array should be 4*8 = 32;
6. If base address of ptr is 6000 then ,

- address of ptr[0] = 6000
- address of ptr[1] = 6008
- address of ptr[2] = 6016
- address of ptr[3] = 6024

Why in the answers mentioned here took addresses as 6000, 6001, 6002, 6003?

Please do provide clarity for the same.

Comment: What are "the answers mentioned here" which you are referring to? And why not use `sizeof` to check the size?

Comment: "And since every pointer is of unsigned int data type" --- this is incorrect but subsequent reasoning doesn't use this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

```
char **ptr[] = {s+3,s+2,s+1,s};
```

`ptr` is an 4 elements array of pointer to pointer to char.

So its size is `4 * sizeof(char **)` and on the systems where pointers are 8 bytes long, it will be 32 bytes : https://godbolt.org/z/WMcojE858
On the 32 bit system where pointers are 4 bytes long it will be 16 bytes: https://godbolt.org/z/4Ef4n81xf

> And since every pointer is of unsigned int data type hence the size of
> ptr array should be = (no. of elements x size of a pointer)

No, it is not an integer type - it is a pointer type.

```
address of ptr[3] = 6024
```

And this pointer is 8 bytes long so the last byte occupied will be 6031 which makes 32 bytes long array of pointers

> Why in the answers mentioned here took addresses as 6000, 6001, 6002,
> 6003?

I do not know what answer you mention, but the pointer arithmetic does not work on chars only on the whole type of pointer (in our case `char **`). It is something which probably confuses you

So `ptr + 1` is **NOT** one byte beyond `ptr` only one `char **` beyond `ptr`. `ptr + 1` is the same as `&ptr[1]` or `*(ptr + 1)` is an equivalent of `ptr[1]`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `ptr` is declared as having an array type

```
char **ptr[] = {s+3,s+2,s+1,s};
```

The size of an array is equal to the number of elements in the array multiplied by the size of element of the array.

As the number of elements in the array declaration shown above is not specified explicitly then it is determined by the number of initializers. In case of the declaration the number of elements is equal to `4`.

So the size of the array is equal to `4 * sizeof( char ** )`. The size of the pointer is implementation defined and depends on the used system. It can be usually equal to either `4` or `8`.

So the size of the array either equal to `16` or `32` bytes.

As for your question about the addresses of elements  `ptr[i]` then if you will run this simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
   const char *s[] = {"ice","green","cone","please"};
   const char **ptr[] = {s+3,s+2,s+1,s};
   const char ***p = ptr;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        printf( "&ptr[%zu] = %p\n", i, ( void * )( ptr + i ) );
    }
}
```

then its output might look like

```
&ptr[0] = 0x7fff8f42d400
&ptr[1] = 0x7fff8f42d408
&ptr[2] = 0x7fff8f42d410
&ptr[3] = 0x7fff8f42d418
```

for a system where the size of a pointer is equal to `8` bytes.

As for the values stored in the expressions `ptr[i]`  then they are implementation defined and specify addresses of first characters of string literals. For example equal string literals can be stored as one character array or as different character arrays dependent on compiler options.

Pay attention to that according to the pointer arithmetic if you have an array declared like

```
T a[N];
```

where `T` is a type specifier when the difference between addresses of adjacent elements `&a[i+1] - &a[i]` is equal to `sizeof( T )`.